# Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::resize does not exist on laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, image, resize

I have working code for saving image until I decided to add a resize function. I have already done the following:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

added this on $providers

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

and this on $aliases

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

on my controller I add this

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

but actually I don't know where to put the resize ( **"resize(900, 900);"** ) so I have this,

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2012',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::User();

    if($user->avatar !== 'user.jpg'){
      $folder = 'avatars';
      Storage::delete($folder.'/'.$user->avatar);
    }

    $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->avatar->resize(900, 900);
    $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);

    $user->avatar = $avatarName;
    $user->save();

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

and here's the error

[image]

can anyone help me to figure this out? Thank you so much in advance.

**SOLUTION base from @Snapey**

```
    $canvas = Image::canvas(900, 900);

    $image = Image::make($request->avatar);
    $image->resize(900,900,
        function($constraint)
            {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
    
    $canvas->insert($image, 'center');       
    $path = Storage::path('avatars');
    $canvas->save($path . '/' . $avatarName);
```

I added a canvas so that the photo will remain proportional instead of look stretched image.

Comment: try `Image::make($request->avatar)->resize(900, 900);` instead

Comment: thanks for responding! the error is gone but it is not resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Intervention Image object from the uploaded file, then resize and save it

```
    $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $image = Image::make($request->avatar);
    $image->resize(900, 900);
    $path = Storage::disk('avatars')->path();
    $image->save($path . '/' . $avatarName);
```

Comment: Note that resizing will stretch the uploaded image to a square, not respecting the aspect ratio. See the examples https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/resize for resizing with aspect ratio maintained

Comment: it now says "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" :(

Comment: this line, $path = Storage::disk('avatars')->path(); , triggers the error, Trying to access array offset on value of type null.

Comment: sorry I thought avatars was the name of a storage disk, instead `$path = Storage::path('avatars');`